# HTTP Post with scala and Dispatch?

Tags: scala, rest, flickr, scala-dispatch

I want to write a function for uploading photos to flickr as http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html. I wrote the following code:

```
val http = new Http with thread.Safety
val uploadEndPoint = :/("api.flickr.com") / "services" / "upload"
```

then I sign the method using dispatch

```
def signUploadRequest(userParams: Map[String, String], accessToken: Token, verifier: String): Map[String, String] = {
    var map = userParams
    map += "api_key" -> consumerKey
    sign("", uploadEndPoint.toString, userParams, consumer, Some(accessToken), Some(verifier), Some(OAuth.oob))
  }
```

Then I call the following method:

def sendUploadRequest(reqParms: Map[String, String]) = {
    http(uploadEndPoint.POST <:< reqParms as_str)
  }

but I got the following error:

```
<rsp stat="fail">
    <err code="100" msg="Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)" />
</rsp>
```

I use the same procedure for requests and it works fine. What is the problem with the Post?

Thanks,
Feras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this flickr api, but shouldn't the map pass as the request body ?

Another remark is that, they say that the photo can't be part of the signature (just in case the `userParams` contains its).

So, if you should use post's body instead of putting the map in the headers (which does `<:<`):

```
def sendUploadRequest(reqParms: Map[String, String]) = { http(uploadEndPoint << reqParms as_str) }
```

The `<<` convert the request to post, using the given map as the payload. Note that using `POST` will set the Map body as empty.

Comment: I don't use photo in the signature and when I changed the verb to << I got the following error: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
Exception in thread "main" dispatch.StatusCode: Unexpected response code: 401
oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=POST

Comment: Should I choose a different http executor for the post?

Comment: Looking there :http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html. at the 9.1 §, they say how to use auth. Some parameters must be provided as query params. So for those ones, api_key, and so on, use must use `<<?`